# UILabel in UITableViewCell takes up extra space when set to fixed number of lines

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a label inside a table view cell. I have set the label to a number of lines, 2. However, if the text is larger it takes up the space as if it had no line restriction and was displaying the full text. Even though it is displaying just two lines.

Constraints for that display label are below. All the other elements are top to bottom 5 points between from the top of the container down to the bottom. If the text is 2 lines or less, there is no extra space. Has anyone experienced this or found a fix for it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you can add a background color to the textfield to check whether the textfield or the constraints are the problem. I think the textfields height would be changed to a wrong height, if you have two lines. A workaround is to set constraints per code, but I'm sure, there must be a better solution. ;)

Comment: @SeanStayn Yeah I know it's the height of the text field that's the issue. If the text field has one line, it hugs fine. If the text field has 5 lines, it takes up the space of 5 lines but only shows 2 when it should be just taking up the space of 2 lines.

Comment: have you tried to use a textview instead?

Comment: The text is a variable length text that I want to fit only two lines of text @SeanStayn. A textview wouldn't be able to accomplish that.

Comment: What LineBreakMode are you using for your UILabel? Are you always testing with text like "NameNameNameName" that has no spaces in it?

Comment: The default line break mode. I haven't changed that, just upped the lines to 2. Also, I've tested with text that has spaces and non-spaces with the same results @MikeTaverne.

Comment: You might try testing with different line break modes. Does changing to Truncate Tail instead of Word Wrap make any difference?

Comment: @MikeTaverne That doesn't affect anything. Played with some of those already.

Comment: @steventnorris it's quite hard to understand what happened in your case. Could you explain it a little bit and provide code for your table view? By the way, what is table view's row height?

Comment: Could you create a minimum example, e.g. as new project on GitHub?

Comment: Perhaps the content hugging priority of your label is too low. Try making it higher (e.g. 1000 just for testing). May there be a conflict with the compression of the parental view/cell?

Comment: @trungduc The row's height is set automatically to fill the space it needs for the content. The row height is behaving appropriately, but the UILabel is taking up more space than 2 lines. It takes up the amount of space as if it were to display all lines, even though it is only showing 2.

Comment: @mschmidt I've played with those as well with no luck. I don't think this is an auto-layout problem thought tbh. It's like the UILabel is calculating its height based on either a line of 0 or like 99, then displaying 2 lines and not adjusting height for it.

Comment: What happens if you call `sizeToFit` on the label after setting the label text?

Comment: @mschmidt I'm actually calling that already and it doesn't help. A few of the labels weren't growing their length to fit their text and sizeToFit fixed that issue, but not this one.

Comment: u may use view debugger to see if it is really because of the label. maybe u have section? without some code it is hard to say.

Comment: @ugur Yeah I checked the view debugger and it's definitely the UILabel causing the issue. No sections. It's an odd error I've never seen before. Driving me nuts.

Comment: A number of lines for the other three label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the other three labels have `numberOfLines` 1.

So here is the working solution

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib..

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 112
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Date label

**Constraints & Content Hugging Priority**

[image: Date Label]

2nd label

**Constraints & Content Hugging Priority**

[image: 2nd Label]

Label thing

**Constraints & Content Hugging Priority**

[image: Label Thing]

Label last one (12:00 AM)

**Constraints & Content Hugging Priority**

[image: Time label]

> Result:

[image: Result in iPhone X]

For detail info please refer to this link 
[Demo Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c0HR8o0oUvswPDaWZuoPNXd_tS0V4Pg5)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: No one was really able to provide any answer for me. I'm thinking there may be some extension in a library I'm using or something that's mucking things up. I'm going to have to go digging or set a static height, which feels janky. That said, my bounty is expiring soon and this is the correct way to do the self-sizing auto-layout stuff, so I'm going to mark it correct in case anyone else hits this issue with a more typical problem that isn't as bizarre as mine.

Comment: Thanks, @steventnorris :) So your problem is resolved or are you still facing some issues?

Comment: Still facing problems, but I haven't had a chance yet to dig deeper into potential extension collisions that might cause this. (pre-existing code base, so I might be missing something)

Comment: Can you able to share your code with me so I will help you to resolve it quickly?

Comment: No worries. I found it. There was an extension overriding some of the draw functionality causing an issue.

Comment: Okay. that's great :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want you label to grow higher than expected.

```
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

If you are using nib/storyboard. simply change `content hugging priority` to `1000`

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: The issue is not the height of the cell, it is the height of the UILabel. I have the cells to automatic dimension now. The UILabel is limited to 2 lines, but is taking up as many lines as it needs. For instance, a 10 line text will take up 10 lines of space, then only show two of those lines dead center instead of hugging those two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have Constrains you need to tell UILabel that you will handle more than 1 line on your UILabel. Also you may need to resize your tableview cell/row when this happens to so they can adapt.

Make sure tableview will adapt.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65.0
}
```

To solve UILabel issue

```
let subTitleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "My String"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22).bold()
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.773, green: 0.776, blue: 0.773, alpha: 1.0)
    label.numberOfLines = 0 // <---- change number of lines
    label.fitTextToBounds()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // <--- only if using constrains
    label.textAlignment = .left
    return label
```

Comment: I don't want it to be more than 2 lines. I want it to be 2 lines, but only fill the space of 1 line. It's taking up space like it has 10 lines, when i'm limiting it to 2.

Comment: @steventnorris then the viewWillAppear will solve that. But make sure your label's anchor top is anchored to bottom of the label you want to adapt.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I'm already doing this, and the cells resize themselves just fine. The issue isn't he cell size, it's the size of the UILabel not properly matching it's text.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i uses this function , if the screen is smaller, it will auto shrink it to the minimum size that u've set. 
hope this helps.

[Minimum Font Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXs4v.png)